# An Application Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-functions

I want to prove the following question, which is found in [this](https://github.com/hduongtrong/ST205A/blob/master/Final/2013%20205A%20final.pdf) practice exam:
[image]

My attempt so far is as follows - I just can't show that the $\sum E(Y_i)$ converges.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $$0 = E X_i = E[ X_i 1_{|X_i| \leq 1}] +   E[ X_i 1_{|X_i| > 1}] = E[Y_i] + E[ X_i 1_{|X_i| > 1}]. $$

Thus $$|E[Y_i]| \leq E[|X_i| 1_{|X_i| > 1}] \leq E[\psi(X_i)].$$

Comment: I really should have seen this - it uses pretty much the same set of ideas I already had there.  Sorry about that, and thanks for the help